# Depression of freezing point

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, colligative-properties

Recently, I learnt that by adding a non-volatile solute to a solvent, the  vapour pressure of the solution is decreased and consequently its boiling point.

**Facts and definitions**

**freezing point**: "The temperature at which the vapour pressure of the substance in its liquid phase is equal to its vapour pressure in the solid phase."

So as the solution cools down, the vapour pressure decreases and eventually equals the vapour pressure of the solid.

**My argument as to why depression in freezing point shouldn’t take place**

consider this argument:the atmospheric pressure is constant regardless of the temperature of the solution.

As we cool down a solution, we are basically removing the kinetic energy of the solution's particles  so due to less kinetic energy and due to atmospheric pressure the Van der Waal's forces come to play, hence turning the solution into a solid state.

the pressure exerted on the liquid by the atmosphere is the same whether you add a solute or not, so no depression of freezing point should take place.

**Reality check**

I know that this argument is not true, as experiments proves the colligative properties are true.

Where and why my "**intuitive**" argument is failing?

Comment: Kindly reopen the question , I have tried my best to make it understandable and aesthetic.

Comment: I still don't get it, but there is one obvious error in your reasoning: The atmospheric pressure is totally irrelevant, only the partial pressure of the substance in question plays a role.

Answer (score 2):

You argument is largely based on enthalpy, whereas freezing point depression and boiling point elevation is (in the situation when the solute only weakly interacts with the solvent) mainly an entropic phenomenon.

Because of the increased entropy by adding a solute (i.e. there are more configurations by having two types of molecules instead of one), the solution will liquify at a lower temperature as compared to the pure solvent and with a similar reasoning, the boiling point will increase with respect to the pure solvent.

Comment: but the reason given by my teacher and and textbooks is that , add solute -vapour pressure decreases-bp and mp decreases-as they are dependent on the pressure above the solution

Comment: Perhaps I am overlooking something, but to the best of my knowledge the boiling point increases when you add a weak-interacting solute to a solvent. For instance, have a look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling-point_elevation Did your teacher (or textbook) by any chance mentioned some additional details?

Comment: yeah boiling of liquids takes place when vapour pressure is equal or greater than atmospheric pressure

Comment: but adding of solute decreases the vapor pressure. now the elevation of boiling point completely makes sense to me whereas depression in freezing point does not

Comment: this statement "weak-interacting solute to a solvent" is true for raoult's law-ideal solutions

Comment: For strongly interacting solutes, you would indeed expect the boiling point to decrease as more energy is required to bring the solvent into the gas phase. That does not readily explain the freezing point depression, as by the same reasoning you would expect the freezing point to increase if the interaction is stronger. If on the other hand the interaction between solute and solvent is similar in both liquid as well as the solid phase, then the entropy argument comes back into play.

Comment: my bad sorry it goes like this, the reason why the vapor pressure (total) decreases because the non-volatile solute takes up some space on the the surface hence not much solvent particles are permitted to escape. also i read somewhere that even solvent and solute interaction can decreases vapor pressure. im not sure of second one but first one is true

Comment: No need to apologise. I am happy you found the reason. The devil lies in the details. :-)

Comment: also the statement "weak-interacting solute to a solvent" doesn't apply for colligative  property, the property only depends on concentration of solute in solvent . the interactions between them doesn't matter. also bp and mp increases and decreases resp. only when you add non volatile solute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85632/discussion-between-sudhanva-b-and-ivo-filot).