# Proper explanation for depression of freezing point

Tags: colligative-properties

Why does depression of freezing point takes place if a non-volatile solute is added to the solution?

[Depression of freezing point](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104201/depression-of-freezing-point)

Answer (score 1):

A simple "intuitive" oversimplification: intrusive foreign molecules get caught between solvent molecules, getting in the way of crystallization. That, however, would contradict the similar boiling point elevation.

Another oversimplification: the solute molecules pull the solvent away from the incipient crystals.

Yet another simplistic answer: [osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis) exerts a force on the solvent, pulling it back into solution, away from the pure crystal of solvent.

Perhaps the last explanation is closest to a [statistical analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0407034) of freezing point depression.

Hopefully, chemistry will not be a depressing subject.

Comment: osmosis is also a colligative property, but then both are not very well intuitively understandable. ;-)